Unable to see my funds in my wallet; however, I see them on the blockchain
I see my tokens on the blockchain, but I am unable to see them in my wallet
ETH Balance
0.028837981414942403 ETH
Eth Value
$96.73 (@ $3,354.28/ETH)
Am I able to retrieve it; if not is there a way I can withdraw from Etherscan / blockchain

can you please describe which wallet did you use?
